# Ruby regex or nokogiri for html parser

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I have such html part:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIwMjYxMTgwOTAPFgIeBGd1aWQFIDI1NmYyOTdkZWZhNjQyODhhYTVmOWI4MGE5MzRjNjlhFgJmD2QWAgIDDxYCHgxhdXRvY29tcGxldGUFA29mZhYCAgEPZBYGZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIFDw8WAh4EVGV4dAUO0JLRi9C50LTQuNGC0LVkZAICD2QWAgICD2QWAgIBDxAPFgYeDURhdGFUZXh0RmllbGQFBU5hendhHg5EYXRhVmFsdWVGaWVsZAUQSURXZXJzamVKZXp5a293ZR4LXyFEYXRhQm91bmRnZBAVAwZQb2xza2EHRW5nbGlzaA7QoNGD0YHRgdC60LDRjxUDATEBMgIxNxQrAwNnZ2cWAQICZAIED2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAw9kFgQCAg8PFgQeJk5vQm90X1Jlc3BvbnNlVGltZUtleV9jdGwwMCRjcCROb0JvdElEBnWRyyBNg9BIHiROb0JvdF9TZXNzaW9uS2V5S2V5X2N0bDAwJGNwJE5vQm90SUQFNE5vQm90X1Nlc3Npb25LZXlfY3RsMDAkY3AkTm9Cb3RJRF82MzUxNTE5MTQ3MjUxNzIzNDFkFgICAQ8WAh4PQ2hhbGxlbmdlU2NyaXB0BVl2YXIgZSA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdjdGwwMF9jcF9Ob0JvdElEX3BjbmInKTsgZS5vZmZzZXRXaWR0aCArIGUub2Zmc2V0SGVpZ2h0O2QCAw9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWBAIDD2QWBGYPZBYCAgEPZBYIAgEPDxYGHgpQbGFpblZhbHVlBQQ0RDVoHg5FbmNyeXB0ZWRWYWx1ZQUgMjQxZjdmZGQ3ODIxNGJhYzgyOGNhNzU3ZDY4NWI3Y2IeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCAw8PFgIfC2hkZAIFDw8WAh8LaGRkAgcPFgIfC2dkAgMPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUK0JTQsNC70LXQtWRkAgUPZBYKZg9kFgRmD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8CBRPQktC40LQg0YPRgdC70YPQs9C4ZGQCAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQCAQ9kFgRmD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8CBR7QnNC10YHRgtC+0L3QsNGF0L7QttC00LXQvdC40LVkZAIBD2QWAgIBDxBkZBYAZAICD2QWBGYPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwIFCNCh0YDQvtC6ZGQCAQ9kFgICAQ8QDxYCHgxBdXRvUG9zdEJhY2toFgIeCG9uQ2hhbmdlBR5jYkR6aWVuR29kemluYV9vbkNoYW5nZSh0aGlzKTtkFgBkAgMPZBYEZg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUG0YfQsNGBZGQCAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQCBQ9kFgJmD2QWBAIBDw8WAh8CBSTQl9Cw0YDQtdCz0LjRgdGC0YDQuNGA0L7QstCw0YLRjNGB0Y9kZAIDDw8WAh8CBTbQntGC0YHRg9GC0YHRgtCy0LjQtSDRgdCy0L7QsdC+0LTQvdGL0LUg0LTQsNGC0Ysg0LTQviBkZBgBBR1jdGwwMCRjcCRldmVudE9yZGVyVmFsaWRhdGlvbg8PZDKpAwABAAAA/////wEAAAAAAAAADAIAAABGTVNaX1dXV19LTElFTlQsIFZlcnNpb249Mi4xMi4wLjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAUBAAAATU1TWl9XV1dfS0xJRU5ULktvbnRyb2xraS5FdmVudE9yZGVyVmFsaWRhdGlvbitFdmVudE9yZGVyVmFsaWRhdGlvbkNvbnRyb2xEYXRhBAAAAAtFdmVudE51bWJlchNFdmVudEV4cGlyYXRpb25UaW1lDVNlY3VyaXR5VG9rZW4MTGljem5pa1Rva2VuAwMBAAxTeXN0ZW0uSW50MzJxU3lzdGVtLk51bGxhYmxlYDFbW1N5c3RlbS5EYXRlVGltZSwgbXNjb3JsaWIsIFZlcnNpb249NC4wLjAuMCwgQ3VsdHVyZT1uZXV0cmFsLCBQdWJsaWNLZXlUb2tlbj1iNzdhNWM1NjE5MzRlMDg5XV0IAgAAAAgIAAAAAAoGAwAAACBmNjZlZTgwODEwZWM0ZjcwYThhZjY2ZDcyNDlmNWFjZgEAAAALZGrI7rw4FqPtCexAP1+dCQ7Qps1t">
```

and i try to use such regex:

```
VIEWSTATE = (/<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" \/>/.match body_text)[1]
```

but it seems, that it is working strange, and fetching not all value, but just part of it. In that case, which regex i must use? (note, that part VIEWSTATE" id="_VIEWSTATE" value= is required in regex).

Will be good, if you tell me how)

Comment: You should use Nokogiri... Don't use Regex.

Comment: One problem with your `regex` is that it checks for the HTML to end in ` />` but your example simply ends in `>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), home of [the definitive resource on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Use a proper parser like Nokogiri.  Any problems you have getting it working will be nothing compared to the problems you have trying to parse arbitrary HTML with regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eot
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIwMjYxMTgwOTAPFgIeB">
eot

# using css
nd = doc.at_css('input#__VIEWSTATE')
nd['name'] 
# => "__VIEWSTATE"

# using xpath
nd = doc.at('//div[@id ="__VIEWSTATE"]')
nd['name'] 
# => "__VIEWSTATE"
```

This way you can get every attribute value of the `input` html element.

Comment: And to be specific, the OP wants to retrieve the `nd['value']` if `nd['name']` and `nd['id']` are both `__VIEWSTATE` (I think, although the intention isn't absolutely clear).

Comment: now what? this value is dynamic, and is never same, will nokogiri see if value is ="MYMYMYMY" ?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris The one you are trying is possible using nokogiri. You can insert any logic you want to built..Just parse your html using Nokogiri.

Comment: and what? doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eot
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="">
eot    i see empty 

nd = doc.at_css('input')
puts "wakawaka"
puts nd['value'] 
puts    it doesn't work!

Comment: hello! what can you say? i'll give you code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/cap/text1.html   work's this? me no!

Comment: I can't test right now..As It is not installed in my current machine. But it will work,as I wrote it. Once I will switch to my pc where nokogiri is installed,I will test it.. But it will work I am sure... :)

Comment: maybe better to fetch by id?

Comment: not exactly, maybe something like: doc.at('//div[(@id,"__VIEWSTATE")]').value?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris You wrote the xpath. It should be `doc.at('//div[@id ="__VIEWSTATE"]')['value']` ..That's it.

Comment: all from getting document, than to some variable put this value doc.at('//div[@id ="__VIEWSTATE"]')['value']